# Why Django application exits when jenkins job ends?

Tags: django, jenkins

I run the following command using bash to start a Django application without any problems even  if I exit from that shell.

```
python manage.py runfcgi daemonize=true ...
```

When Jenkins runs same command above, the Django application runs as well as using bash to run. But why the application is killed when the job ends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution here and it works for me
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that Jenkins starts a new shell session for each job, and then closes it when the job is complete. This will terminate any processes started in that session.

If you want a process to persist after closing the session, you can start it with `nohup`:

```
nohup python manage.py runfcgi daemonize=true ...
```

I had a similar problem in the past using fabric - the service would terminate even if I set the daemonize flag to true. I used `nohup` to work around it.

Comment: Thanks. I tried but not working for my case. Django application is still killed after job finishes.